# Flex Chrome now showing up on AIR app when I compile with Flex 4 SDK

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flash-builder

I have an AIR app initially written in Flex 3 that I had removed the Chrome from, but now it shows up when I compile using Flash Builder 4 with Flex 4 SDK. I have

```
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome> 
<transparent>true</transparent>
```

set in the *-app.xml file and showFlexChrome="false" showStatusBar="false" showTitleBar="false" set in the  tag. The status bar is gone, but I still see the title bar appear. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a Flex 4 application all it should take is the changes to app.xml that you mentioned, plus showStatusBar="false" in the root tag. 

It sounds like you are using a Flex 3 application though, so then you should just need to add  showTitleBar="false" which you have.

It works for me. I even tried making a Flex3 project, migrating it to Flex4 and it still worked as expected. Maybe try making a new project, see if you can reproduce the problem, and go from there.

Comment: I have another app that I created from scratch using the Flex 4 SDK and I have the same issue. I have the app.xml vars set and am using the <s:WindowedApplication> tag with showStatusBar="false" and I still see the title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded the Flex 4 SDK and converted an old Flex 3 app over and I also got some odd behaviour on my new spark WindowedApplication. I'm using command line builds (can't afford FlashBuilder) but it should all be the same.

My application was totally missing its TitleBar, however its StatusBar was visible (although without the resize grip). I had similar *-app.xml entries to you, but nothing else mentioning the TitleBar in my code.

After playing around a bit I realised it was the style code in the application's mxml. It used to look like this in Flex 3...

```
<mx:Style>
    WindowedApplication
    {
        background-color:"0x999999";
        background-alpha:"0.8";
    }
</mx:Style>
```

...which got changed to this to compile in Flex 4...

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    WindowedApplication
    {
        background-color:#999999;
        background-alpha:0.8;
    }
</fx:Style>
```

...but I found to fix my main application window, I needed to change it to...

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    WindowedApplication
    {
        skinClass:ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin");
    }
</fx:Style>
```

And now I have a great looking app window with a TitleBar and a StatusBar (with a resize grip as well!). Hope this helps.

Cheers
Drew